# How to always perform a function, regardless of the API route called?

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I am creating a NetCore 2 API and connecting to a SQL Server Database. Is it possible to always call a function no matter what the route is? My example:

For each call I am passing in the necessary parameters to connect to the SQL DB inside the headers. I am going to have hundreds of calls in this api, so I really don't want to duplicate this for every single call:

```cs
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<DEPARTMENT>> Get(
        [FromHeader] string Server, 
        [FromHeader] string Database, 
        [FromHeader] string Username, 
        [FromHeader] string Password, 
        [FromHeader] string Trusted)
    {
        util.SetConnectionString(Server, Database, Username, Password, Trusted);
        return await this.departmentDataProvider.GetDepartments();
    }

    [HttpGet("{DepartmentId}")]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<DEPARTMENT>> Get(
        string DepartmentId,
        [FromHeader] string Server, 
        [FromHeader] string Database, 
        [FromHeader] string Username, 
        [FromHeader] string Password, 
        [FromHeader] string Trusted)
    {
        util.SetConnectionString(Server, Database, Username, Password, Trusted);
        return await this.departmentDataProvider.GetDepartment(DepartmentId);
    }
```

I would like to create an ancestor function that just has the header connection parameters, and the call to set the connection string. End goal would be something like this:

Ancestor:

```cs
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<?>> Get(
        [FromHeader] string Server,
        [FromHeader] string Database,
        [FromHeader] string Username,
        [FromHeader] string Password,
        [FromHeader] string Trusted)
    {
        util.SetConnectionString(Server, Database, Username, Password, Trusted);
    }
```

Children:

```cs
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<DEPARTMENT>> Get()
    {
        return await this.departmentDataProvider.GetDepartments();
    }

    [HttpGet("{DepartmentId}")]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<DEPARTMENT>> Get(string DepartmentId)
    {
        return await this.departmentDataProvider.GetDepartment(DepartmentId);
    }
```

### Edit:

Adding Util.cs & DepartmentDataProvider.cs for more information.

Util.cs

```cs
public static class util
{
    public static string ConnectionString { get; set; }

    public static void SetConnectionString(string Server, string Database, string UserName, string Password, string Trusted)
    {
        if (Trusted == "true")             
            ConnectionString = "Server=" + Server + ";Database=" + Database + ";Trusted_Connection=True;";
        else
            ConnectionString = "Server=" + Server + ";Database=" + Database + ";User ID= " + UserName + ";Password=" + Password + ";Trusted_Connection=False;";
    }

    public static string GetConnectionString()
    {
        return ConnectionString;
    }
}
```

DepartmentDataProvider.cs

```cs
public class DepartmentDataProvider : IDepartmentDataProvider
{
    public async Task<DEPARTMENT> GetDepartment(int DepartmentId)
    {
        string connString = util.GetConnectionString();

        using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(util.GetConnectionString()))
        {
            await sqlConnection.OpenAsync();
            var dynamicParameters = new DynamicParameters();
            dynamicParameters.Add("@DepartmentID", DepartmentId);
            return await sqlConnection.QuerySingleOrDefaultAsync<DEPARTMENT>(
                "Select * From DEPARTMENT Where DEPARTMENT_ID = @DepartmentID",
                dynamicParameters,
                commandType: CommandType.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Checkout [IOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.1). You could use the configuration to store the database settings and retrieve them from the Actions.

Comment: @kirk Util is just a class I use to store the connection string, to be accessed by the data provider, it is a temporary measure for now. I'm guessing that is a very incorrect way to do it, but this is trial by fire for me as I have never worked in c# before. But yes, the goal is to have the connection string be able to be different per call. I need to be able to use the same call for different databases.

Comment: @DaveAgaba Thank you, i will check it out.

Comment: @kirk I don't explicitly create the instance of util... I edited the main post to show what util.cs looks like. Edit: also added department data provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class to encapsulate the connection string data into which any relevant objects will be injected (e.g. maybe the `HttpContext`):

```
public class ConnectingStringParmsFromHeaders
{
    public string Server { get; private set; }
    // other properties

    // ideally you wouldn't depend on ASP.NET Core constructs such as HttContext
    //   but I'm using it here for brevity
    public ConnectionStringPropertiesFromHeaders( HttpContext httpContext )
    {
        ReadPropertiesFromHeaders( httpContext.Request.Headers );
    }

    private void ReadPropertiesFromHeaders( IHeaderDictionary headers )
    {
        // do your header-reading thing here
    }

    public string BuildConnectionString()
    {
        // your Util.SetConnectionString(...) code here
        //   using local instance properties and not static properties
    }
}
```

Next, [register](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.1) this class with lifetime of `Scoped` (single object reused during the same HTTP request):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    services.AddScoped<ConnectionStringParmsFromHeaders>();
}
```

Finally, add a parameter of this type to your controllers' constructors and set a property or field for use in action methods:

```
public class DepartmentsController : Controller
{
    private ConnectionStringParmsFromHeaders ConnStrParms { get; private set; }

    public DepartmentsController( ConnectionStringParmsFromHeaders connStrParms )
    {
        ConnStrParms = connStrParms;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        // for illustrative purposes
        var connStr = connStrParms.BuildConnectionString();

        // remainder of your action method's code
    }
}
```

Note that your `Util` class setting a static property with per-http-request header data is a problem b/c there can be multiple concurrent threads reading and writing with that same property and different data - you'll have no idea if you're using the correct data!  Move the connection string generating code to this new config class so that you can access it on a per-request basis as shown in above's code sample.

The above code may not be 100% accurate as I can't test it right now but it should be enough to get you where you need to go.

Comment: This is great. The only thing I'm still struggling with is how to access the connection string object from the data provider. Do I need to inject it, just like what was done in the constructor of the Controller?

Comment: you could inject the data provider class into your controller the same way and have the conn string data object injected into your data provider class or simply pass the conn string data object into the constructor of the data provider object if you're instantiating it manually/per action method

Comment: Yeah I ended up just passing it in through the constructor. Thanks again for your help.